# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined (Gravatar service)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple app, with one controller, I just want to see in the console what is coming from the `Gravatar.get('example@example.com', 100);` function.

But I have a **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"**. I don't understand why, because I injected the service inside my module, and my controller. Am I calling correctly the **Gravatar.get()** function ?

You can see below my short code, and under the gravatar .js file with the get() function.

```js
//***************************************************************************
//******** My simple controller**********

var main = angular.module('firebaseConfig', ['firebase', 'gravatar']);

main.run(function(){

  // Initialize Firebase
  //*****
  //*****
  //*****
  //*****

});

main.controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout', '$ionicLoading', '$state', '$ionicHistory', 'Gravatar', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $state, $ionicHistory,  $cordovaImagePicker, Gravatar) {

 var grav = Gravatar.get('example@example.com', 100);
 console.log("Grav vaut :", grav);
 
}
//***************************************************************************

// GRAVATAR SERVICE JS FILE :

angular.module('gravatar', [])

.service('Gravatar', [function(){
   
  
    
    var MD5 = function (string) {

       function RotateLeft(lValue, iShiftBits) {
               return (lValue<<iShiftBits) | (lValue>>>(32-iShiftBits));
       }
    
       function AddUnsigned(lX,lY) {
               var lX4,lY4,lX8,lY8,lResult;
               lX8 = (lX & 0x80000000);
               lY8 = (lY & 0x80000000);
               lX4 = (lX & 0x40000000);
               lY4 = (lY & 0x40000000);
               lResult = (lX & 0x3FFFFFFF)+(lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
               if (lX4 & lY4) {
                       return (lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
               }
               if (lX4 | lY4) {
                       if (lResult & 0x40000000) {
                               return (lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
                       } else {
                               return (lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
                       }
               } else {
                       return (lResult ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
               }
       }
    
       function F(x,y,z) { return (x & y) | ((~x) & z); }
       function G(x,y,z) { return (x & z) | (y & (~z)); }
       function H(x,y,z) { return (x ^ y ^ z); }
       function I(x,y,z) { return (y ^ (x | (~z))); }
    
       function FF(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
               a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(F(b, c, d), x), ac));
               return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
       };
    
       function GG(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
               a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(G(b, c, d), x), ac));
               return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
       };
    
       function HH(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
               a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(H(b, c, d), x), ac));
               return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
       };
    
       function II(a,b,c,d,x,s,ac) {
               a = AddUnsigned(a, AddUnsigned(AddUnsigned(I(b, c, d), x), ac));
               return AddUnsigned(RotateLeft(a, s), b);
       };
    
       function ConvertToWordArray(string) {
               var lWordCount;
               var lMessageLength = string.length;
               var lNumberOfWords_temp1=lMessageLength + 8;
               var lNumberOfWords_temp2=(lNumberOfWords_temp1-(lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64))/64;
               var lNumberOfWords = (lNumberOfWords_temp2+1)*16;
               var lWordArray=Array(lNumberOfWords-1);
               var lBytePosition = 0;
               var lByteCount = 0;
               while ( lByteCount < lMessageLength ) {
                       lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
                       lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
                       lWordArray[lWordCount] = (lWordArray[lWordCount] | (string.charCodeAt(lByteCount)<<lBytePosition));
                       lByteCount++;
               }
               lWordCount = (lByteCount-(lByteCount % 4))/4;
               lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4)*8;
               lWordArray[lWordCount] = lWordArray[lWordCount] | (0x80<<lBytePosition);
               lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-2] = lMessageLength<<3;
               lWordArray[lNumberOfWords-1] = lMessageLength>>>29;
               return lWordArray;
       };
    
       function WordToHex(lValue) {
               var WordToHexValue="",WordToHexValue_temp="",lByte,lCount;
               for (lCount = 0;lCount<=3;lCount++) {
                       lByte = (lValue>>>(lCount*8)) & 255;
                       WordToHexValue_temp = "0" + lByte.toString(16);
                       WordToHexValue = WordToHexValue + WordToHexValue_temp.substr(WordToHexValue_temp.length-2,2);
               }
               return WordToHexValue;
       };
    
       function Utf8Encode(string) {
               string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");
               var utftext = "";
    
               for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
    
                       var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
    
                       if (c < 128) {
                               utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
                       }
                       else if((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
                               utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
                               utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                       }
                       else {
                               utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
                               utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
                               utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
                       }
    
               }
    
               return utftext;
       };
    
       var x=Array();
       var k,AA,BB,CC,DD,a,b,c,d;
       var S11=7, S12=12, S13=17, S14=22;
       var S21=5, S22=9 , S23=14, S24=20;
       var S31=4, S32=11, S33=16, S34=23;
       var S41=6, S42=10, S43=15, S44=21;
    
       string = Utf8Encode(string);
    
       x = ConvertToWordArray(string);
    
       a = 0x67452301; b = 0xEFCDAB89; c = 0x98BADCFE; d = 0x10325476;
    
       for (k=0;k<x.length;k+=16) {
               AA=a; BB=b; CC=c; DD=d;
               a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S11,0xD76AA478);
               d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+1], S12,0xE8C7B756);
               c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S13,0x242070DB);
               b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+3], S14,0xC1BDCEEE);
               a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S11,0xF57C0FAF);
               d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+5], S12,0x4787C62A);
               c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S13,0xA8304613);
               b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+7], S14,0xFD469501);
               a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S11,0x698098D8);
               d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+9], S12,0x8B44F7AF);
               c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S13,0xFFFF5BB1);
               b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+11],S14,0x895CD7BE);
               a=FF(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S11,0x6B901122);
               d=FF(d,a,b,c,x[k+13],S12,0xFD987193);
               c=FF(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S13,0xA679438E);
               b=FF(b,c,d,a,x[k+15],S14,0x49B40821);
               a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S21,0xF61E2562);
               d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+6], S22,0xC040B340);
               c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S23,0x265E5A51);
               b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+0], S24,0xE9B6C7AA);
               a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S21,0xD62F105D);
               d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+10],S22,0x2441453);
               c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S23,0xD8A1E681);
               b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+4], S24,0xE7D3FBC8);
               a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S21,0x21E1CDE6);
               d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+14],S22,0xC33707D6);
               c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S23,0xF4D50D87);
               b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+8], S24,0x455A14ED);
               a=GG(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S21,0xA9E3E905);
               d=GG(d,a,b,c,x[k+2], S22,0xFCEFA3F8);
               c=GG(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S23,0x676F02D9);
               b=GG(b,c,d,a,x[k+12],S24,0x8D2A4C8A);
               a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+5], S31,0xFFFA3942);
               d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+8], S32,0x8771F681);
               c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+11],S33,0x6D9D6122);
               b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+14],S34,0xFDE5380C);
               a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+1], S31,0xA4BEEA44);
               d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+4], S32,0x4BDECFA9);
               c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+7], S33,0xF6BB4B60);
               b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+10],S34,0xBEBFBC70);
               a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+13],S31,0x289B7EC6);
               d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+0], S32,0xEAA127FA);
               c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+3], S33,0xD4EF3085);
               b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+6], S34,0x4881D05);
               a=HH(a,b,c,d,x[k+9], S31,0xD9D4D039);
               d=HH(d,a,b,c,x[k+12],S32,0xE6DB99E5);
               c=HH(c,d,a,b,x[k+15],S33,0x1FA27CF8);
               b=HH(b,c,d,a,x[k+2], S34,0xC4AC5665);
               a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+0], S41,0xF4292244);
               d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+7], S42,0x432AFF97);
               c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+14],S43,0xAB9423A7);
               b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+5], S44,0xFC93A039);
               a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+12],S41,0x655B59C3);
               d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+3], S42,0x8F0CCC92);
               c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+10],S43,0xFFEFF47D);
               b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+1], S44,0x85845DD1);
               a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+8], S41,0x6FA87E4F);
               d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+15],S42,0xFE2CE6E0);
               c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+6], S43,0xA3014314);
               b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+13],S44,0x4E0811A1);
               a=II(a,b,c,d,x[k+4], S41,0xF7537E82);
               d=II(d,a,b,c,x[k+11],S42,0xBD3AF235);
               c=II(c,d,a,b,x[k+2], S43,0x2AD7D2BB);
               b=II(b,c,d,a,x[k+9], S44,0xEB86D391);
               a=AddUnsigned(a,AA);
               b=AddUnsigned(b,BB);
               c=AddUnsigned(c,CC);
               d=AddUnsigned(d,DD);
            }
    
        var temp = WordToHex(a)+WordToHex(b)+WordToHex(c)+WordToHex(d);
    
        return temp.toLowerCase();
    }
    
    var ret = {
        'get': function(email, size){
            if (!email) return;
            size = size || 80;
            return 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' + MD5(email) + '.jpg?s=' + size;
        }
    }
    
    return ret;

}])

.directive('gravatarSrc', [
  'Gravatar',
function(Gravatar) {

  return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var watchVal = attrs['gravatarSrc'];
            var watchSize = parseInt(attrs['gravatarSize']) || 80;
            scope.$watch(watchVal, function(val) {
              element.attr('src', Gravatar.get(val, watchSize));
            });
          }
        };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not injected `$cordovaImagePicker` as dependencies. Thus the service `Gravatar` is mapped with `$cordovaImagePicker` object in the controller

*Use*

```
main.controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout', '$ionicLoading', '$state', '$ionicHistory', '$cordovaImagePicker', 'Gravatar',
 function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $state, $ionicHistory,  $cordovaImagePicker, Gravatar) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one of the injections ($cordovaImagePicker):

```
main.controller("Ctrl", ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout', '$ionicLoading', '$state', '$ionicHistory', '$cordovaImagePicker', 'Gravatar', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $ionicPopup, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $state, $ionicHistory, $cordovaImagePicker, Gravatar) {

  var grav = Gravatar.get('example@example.com', 100);
  console.log("Grav vaut :", grav);

}
```